# About Twitter Integration Using OAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying Twitter Integration Using OAuth. Everything is fine but when I compiled and run it gives only a screen which shows my own button and textfield with gray screen, which I hav added in xib, not screen with tweeter.

Here is my code

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if (!self.engine) {

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    self.engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    self.engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

}


if (![self.engine isAuthorized]) {

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:self.engine 
                                    delegate:self];

      if(controller) {

           [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    }


}
```

}

Comment: what have you done put some code??

Comment: which library are you using, and please show us some code

Comment: I have done evrything like in this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/comment-page-2/#comments

Comment: Why integrate twitter using OAuth while you have readily available [Apple twitter framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) ?

Comment: Have you considered using the iOS 5 Twitter framework? It will save you many headaches and is only a few lines of code to send a tweet.

Comment: but currently i am using ios4.

Comment: 70% of iOS users have upgraded to iOS 5 since it was launched so would be nice to go with Apple teitter framework